# How do I modify the node content with Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I have a script like this:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'  
require 'json' 

data = File.read("data.json")
obj = JSON.parse(data)
puts obj.values

@page = Nokogiri::HTML(open("template.panoramatemplate"))

recipename = @page.xpath("//body/h1") 
recipename.content = "hello"
puts teachername
```

I have an HTML file that is pretty basic:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title><* page.title *></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1><* recipe.name *></h1>
    <* food name *>
      <* food.name *>
      <* more values *>
        <p><* value *></p>
      <* ENDEACH *>
    <* ENDEACH *>
  </body>
</html>
```

I looked at this section: http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/modifying_an_html_xml_document.html

The first example is changing text content. I tried to follow that example, but I am getting:

```
undefined method content= for [#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x80d1fb98 name="h1">]:Nokogiri::XML::NodeSet (NoMethodError)
```

Am I opening the document incorrectly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nokogiri will return a [`NodeSet`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/NodeSet.html) to an `xpath` query (also `search` and `css`). This is an Enumerable object of [`Node`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html)s

If you know your element is the only one:

```
recipename = @page.xpath("//body/h1").first
```

Or you can loop through the NodeSet with `.each` if needed

```
recipename = @page.xpath("//body/h1")
recipename.each do |node|
  puts node.content
end
```

Comment: Nokogiri *might* return a NodeSet to a query, depending on the method used. `search`, `css` and `xpath` return a NodeSet. `at`, `at_css` and `at_xpath` return a Node.

Answer (score 5):

There are several things wrong. The first is that you're asking Nokogiri to parse something that *looks kinda like* HTML but isn't. Nokogiri is smart enough to know the difference:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<html>
  <head>
    <title><* page.title *></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1><* recipe.name *></h1>
    <* food name *>
      <* food.name *>
      <* more values *>
        <p><* value *></p>
      <* ENDEACH *>
    <* ENDEACH *>
  </body>
</html>
EOT

puts doc.to_html
# >> <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
# >> <html>
# >>   <head>
# >> <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=US-ASCII">
# >>     <title></title>
# >>   </head>
# >>   <body>
# >>     <h1></h1>
# >>     
# >>       
# >>       
# >>         <p></p>
# >>       
# >>     
# >>   </body>
# >> </html>
```

Notice the chunks in the output? Here's what Nokogiri has to say about the HTML:

```
doc.errors
# => [#<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: htmlParseStartTag: invalid element name>,
#     #<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: htmlParseStartTag: invalid element name>,
#     #<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: htmlParseStartTag: invalid element name>,
#     #<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: htmlParseStartTag: invalid element name>,
#     #<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: htmlParseStartTag: invalid element name>,
#     #<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: htmlParseStartTag: invalid element name>,
#     #<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: htmlParseStartTag: invalid element name>,
#     #<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: htmlParseStartTag: invalid element name>]
```

So, you can't expect Nokogiri to handle a template unless that template is valid HTML.

After stripping out the invalid tags and simplifying the HTML, here's the next issue:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>foo</h1>
  </body>
</html>
EOT

h1 = doc.search('h1')
h1.class # => Nokogiri::XML::NodeSet
h1.respond_to?(:content=) # => false
```

Notice that using `search` returns a NodeSet, which doesn't understand `content=`. `search`, along with `css` and `xpath` returns a NodeSet. You *could* iterate over that returned NodeSet and work on individual Nodes, but, as is, trying to set the same content to a bunch of Nodes in a NodeSet isn't logical, so Nokogiri doesn't implement it.

Instead:

```
h1 = doc.at('h1')
h1.class # => Nokogiri::XML::Element
h1.respond_to?(:content=) # => true
h1.content = 'hello'
```

`at`, `at_css` and `at_xpath` are equivalent to using `search('some selector').first`, which is why they return just a Node.

Looking at the DOM now:

```
puts doc.to_html

# >> <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
# >> <html>
# >>   <body>
# >>     <h1>hello</h1>
# >>   </body>
# >> </html>
```

Comment: your answer is probably a better approach.

Comment: It might, but you *need* to understand why and why you might not want to follow that particular path. Understanding what you're doing and how to selectively pick one way of doing something vs. another is important, especially when you're dealing with very complex documents and speed is important.

Comment: I understand but unfortunately the template in question is of very little importance.